# Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'scoreToAdd' of 'LogicScript.addScore(int)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a very new and not very smart user in Unity. I am making a Flappy Bird type game as my first project following some YouTube tutorials. The scripts I have a problem in are made for increasing the score in the game when you go through the pipes.

Here is the code for the script and a code for one of the other script I used because they are connected.

The first script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipeMiddleScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LogicScript logic;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicScript>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        logic.addScore();
    }
}
```

the second script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int playerScore;
    public Text scoreText;

    [ContextMenu("Increase Score")]
    public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {
        playerScore = playerScore + scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();


    }

    [ContextMenu("Decrease Score")]
    public void removeScore()
    {
        playerScore = playerScore - 1;
        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();


    }
   
}
```

I tried using some of Unity's autofixes but none worked. i also tried to google the error but nothing makes sense.

The closest I got was I didn't get any error in visual studio but I still have one in unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two bugs here so make sure you understand why you wrote every part of your code.
When you call addscore in the pipemiddle script you need to pass a parameter. Replace it with:

```
logic.addScore(1);
```

Assuming you want to increase the score by one.

You will get another error though. you cannot just run getcomponent and assume it assigns to the variable, you need to replace:

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicScript>();
```

```
logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicScript>();
```

What you did was the same as making an int foo and just writing 4 + 5.
woo will not be 9, you need to write foo = 4 + 5;

I know that little errors like this are really annoying. When you misspell something or forget something but the most important thing is that you learn. If you have more problems in this script please respond.

Comment: Thanks a lot didn't know about the other error but I fixed both and it works now.

Comment: If my answer helped you could upvote it or click the checkmark to symbolize it was the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `addScore` function:

```
public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
{
    playerScore = playerScore + scoreToAdd;
    scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();
}
```

Do you notice the `int scoreToAdd` part of your function's definition? That means that the function you wrote is expecting you to pass an `int` into it as an argument. In your `OnTriggerEnter2D` function, you don't pass an integer to it. You just call `logic.addScore()` without any arguments, which is what the error is trying to tell you.

In this case, you need to pass an integer along to your `addScore` function. This would make your `OnTriggerEnter2D` function look like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // 1 is just an example.
    logic.addScore(1);
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `scoreToAdd` argument and just add a constant to the player's score:

```
public void addScore()
{
    // Again, 1 is just an example.
    playerScore = playerScore + 1;
    scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();
}
```